# Bigquery table update failing due to backend error all of suddenly

Tags: google-bigquery

I am facing an issue with the Bigquery update job which was executing fine till a few days back and started failing all of suddenly due to the backend error

Error:-'backendError', And it is suggesting to retry would solve the problem but it is not the case.

Can someone help on this, I am trying to update the partition table from a nonpartitioned table based on non-part fields.

Comment: Please provide the rough command that you used. For instance, I don't know what is to "update the partition table from a nonpartitioned table ...", is it a SQL query or a commandline command?

Comment: merge into
  `dataset_id.target_table_name` as final
using
  `dateset_id.source_table_name` as source
on
  final.id = source.id and
  final.run_dte =source.run_dte
when matched then
update set
  trvl_cnt = source.trvl_cnt,
  rcnt_trvl_ind = source.rcnt_trvl_ind,
  trip_dte = source.trip_dte
  
Above is the query, trip_dte is partition column in the table, when I run the merge on the trip date it works. Am i hititng any BQ limitations. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any suggestions?